# How do I get consecutive weeks days in mysql

Tags: mysql

This is my query:

```
SELECT (HOUR(TIMEDIFF(i.StartTime,'18:30:00'))*60) + MINUTE(TIMEDIFF(i.StartTime,'18:30:00')) AS f_day,
        (HOUR(TIMEDIFF(i.StartTime,i.EndTime))*60) + MINUTE(TIMEDIFF(i.StartTime,i.EndTime)) AS current,
        i.StartDate, i.EndDate, i.StartTime, i.EndTime, i.id
    FROM `request` r 
    INNER JOIN `interval` i ON r.id = i.requestId
    WHERE r.userId ='xxxx' 

    AND r.eventId = '5' AND r.statusId = '2'

    ORDER BY i.StartDate ASC
```

And this is the result:[image]

Is there a way to check if there exists 10 consecutives weekdays? 
In my case for instance the result should be the last 2 rows
**2015-07-28   --- 2015-07-30  => 3 days and 2015-07-31 --- 2015-08-10 => 7days. So it is 10 consecutive days**

Comment: You could have made a single php/mysql question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31380670/getting-consecutives-days-in-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be simple enough:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(EndDate, StartDate)+1 AS consecutive_days;
```

returns

```
EndDate    | StartDate  | consecutive_days
2015-07-30 | 2015-07-28 |                3
2015-08-10 | 2015-07-31 |               11
```

Comment: ok, but is there  a way to make a count only on weekdays ? so not sunday and saturday ? thx a lot!

Comment: I see. I didn't get that particular condition from the question. That requires more thinking indeed.

Comment: If it's all the same to you, I'll switch to the php version of this question. It will be less convoluted than a mysql solution.

Comment: Having gained better understanding of the question, I realize now this is a pretty poor answer.